# How to use gupnp-upload?

Tags: linux, command-line, upnp

I just learned that there is `sudo apt install gupnp-tools` in Ubuntu; where I can perform a UPNP discovery:

```
$ gssdp-discover
Using network interface wlp3s0
Scanning for all resources
Showing "available" messages
...
resource available
  USN:      uuid:e04d4bbc-8b30-6c8c-bcbc-faafb717f98f::urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1
  Location: http://192.168.0.152:38389/deviceDescription/MediaServer
...
```

Here, there is a command `gupnp-upload`; there is no man page, the only documentation is:

```
$ gupnp-upload -h
Usage:
  gupnp-upload [OPTION?] - Upload files to UPnP MediaServer

Help Options:
  -h, --help                          Show help options

Application Options:
  -t, --search-timeout=seconds        Search Timeout
  -c, --container-id=CONTAINER_ID     Destination Container ID
  -i, --title=TITLE                   Title for item
  -e, --interface=INTERFACE           Network interface to search MediaServer on
  -u, --udn=UDN                       UDN of the device to upload to
```

And the only example on the internet for its use I found is [Re: How to use the rygel upload service?](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/rygel-list/2015-November/msg00004.html):

> > ```
> > Finally, I try to upload a picture:
> > Â Â Â $ gupnp-upload -i lo uuid:8aa83fb8-c1d8-445a-98c1-76d3d22847bf 
> > gnome-logo.png
> > Â Â Â ** (gupnp-upload:27841): CRITICAL **: Failed to find a suitable 
> > container for upload.
> > It fails!
> > What kind of "container" is missing?
> > ```
>
> ```
> Does it work if you use -c "DLNA_ORG.AnyContainer"? The gupnp-upload is
> a bit stupid and only searches the first level of containers for a
> container with a suitable upload-class.
>
> -c "DLNA_ORG.AnyContainer" will ask the server to find one.
> ```

So, from my discovery above, I try:

```
$ gupnp-upload -i hello.jpg -c "DLNA_ORG.AnyContainer" uuid:e04d4bbc-8b30-6c8c-bcbc-faafb717f98f hello.jpg
File uuid:e04d4bbc-8b30-6c8c-bcbc-faafb717f98f does not exist
UPnP context created for interface wlp3s0 (192.168.0.45)

** (gupnp-upload:53645): CRITICAL **: 08:58:25.711: gupnp_control_point_new: assertion 'target' failed

(gupnp-upload:53645): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 08:58:25.711: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(gupnp-upload:53645): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 08:58:25.711: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

** (gupnp-upload:53645): CRITICAL **: 08:58:25.711: gssdp_resource_browser_set_active: assertion 'GSSDP_IS_RESOURCE_BROWSER (resource_browser)' failed
```

Well, obviously, that wasn't that.

So, can anyone give an example, of how can I upload with `gupnp-upload` to a UPNP device which `gssdp-discover` has listed as "resource available"?